# protractor in connection with selenium keeps connecting to localhost

Tags: javascript, angular, selenium, protractor

I have a setup of my angular-app and a separate selenium server as docker-compose setup

my protractor setting looks like this

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
    specs: [
        './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
    ],
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },

    directConnect: false,
    baseUrl: 'http://user-frontend:4200/',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://selenium:4444/wd/hub',
    framework: 'jasmine',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
        print: function() {}
    },
    onPrepare() {
        require('ts-node').register({
            project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
        });
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
    }
};
```

now I run the command to run the end2end tests using protractor:

```
ng e2e --no-serve
```

All my tests are failing, and when I debug the selenium server and take screenshots, I see it is trying to connect to itself (localhost) instead of back to the application host `baseUrl: 'http://user-frontend:4200/',`

[image]

any Idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I use `testUrl` instead of `baseUrl`. Unsure if they are treated the same way, but its worth a try

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `browser.baseUrl` (or `browser.get()`) is not set elsewhere?